# Date parameter for SSCE database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

Could someone provide and explain a sample query for data parameter SQL Server Compact databse

Is it like:

```
"Where DTE between Date1 and Date2"
```

Or am I completely off?

Comment: Present table and columns please

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name
BETWEEN @value1 AND @value2